# Ionic Inappbrowser: Custom Events

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I would like to receive a custom Event from the Webpage running inside the Ionic In-App-Browser.

For example:

```
 this.browser.on('buttonOnWebSitePressed').subscribe(event => {
  that.browser.hide();
});
```

Is that possible? If so: How do I need to throw the event from the Webpage

Or does .on(...) only work with events like loadstart, loadstop, loaderror or exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the docs of the [InAppBrowserPlugin (Cordova)](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowseraddeventlistener).

As far as I can see, there are only four possible events (in this plugin) to catch from your ionic application:

- **loadstart**: event fires when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL.
- **loadstop**: event fires when the InAppBrowser finishes loading a URL.
- **loaderror**: event fires when the InAppBrowser encounters an error when loading a URL.
- **exit**: event fires when the InAppBrowser window is closed.

Edit:
There are some workarounds. One is to call a URL via a button in injected into the inappbrowser and then check the "loadstart" event for that URL.

Comment: it worked. I used `loadstart` to detect change in my url and it worked.